# Resize textarea with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. How to resize a divs when resizing textarea within it?
2. If I create two or more sticky and use ESC all sticky will be closed. How to set up the ESC to close only active pop-up?
3. How to keep alive sticky when page is refreshing?

I use this code to make a pop-up sticky note: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXNBoz**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
         function limitTextareaLine(e) {
                        if(e.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val().split("\n").length >= $(this).attr('rows')) { 
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    $(function() {
                      $('textarea.limited').keydown(limitTextareaLine);
                    });      
                    var x = "<div class='darkYellow'><div class='close'>X</div>Note<div class='lightYellow'><textarea maxlength='250' rows='8' cols='25' class='limited'></textarea></div></div>";    
                    $('#click').click(function () { 
                        $('#one').append('<div class="note">'+x+'</div>');
                        $( ".darkYellow" ).draggable();
                        $('.close').each(function(){
                            $('.close').click(function() {
                                $(this).parent().remove();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    $('.darkYellow').live('click', function() {
                      $(this).addClass("index");
                    });
                    $('.darkYellow').live('blur', function() {
                      $(this).removeClass("index");
                    }); 
            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
                    window.open(location, '_self', '');
                    openedWindow.close();
                }
            });
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Now all we can do is guess, so please post a minimum working code snippet to get the best answer.

Comment: May I suggest that you add a resize function to your draggable `div` instead and have the `textarea` adjust to that. This way even browsers that don't have `textarea` resize handle will be resizeable.

Comment: Here is new actually work code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXNBoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the fixed width and height to min-width and min-height like below.

And it should auto resize.

```
*{
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
 }

.darkYellow {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #76B5F0;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:150px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-indent:1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #888888;
  cursor:move
    }

.lightYellow {    
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:135px;
  background-color: #8EC0EE;
  margin-top:1px;
}

textarea {  
 background-color: #8EC0EE;     
 border: 0px;  
}

.index {
 z-index: 55;    
}

.close {
 width:7px;
 height:7px;
 padding:0;
 line-height:2pt;
 float:right;
 margin-top:6px;
 margin-right:4px;
 font-size:14px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

also use a more up to date version of JQuery, I've updated you fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/gLrmgqgz/10/

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have to try found solution for make a "alive session" for any sticky when page will be refreshed.

Comment: This will not work in IE. Even Edge does not support css resize. I'd suggest using jQuery UI's resize function

Answer (score 0):

In CSS set the parent div's display to display: table should fix the problem and make it resize as you change the textarea's size.

EDIT: As for the escape thing (just refreshed and saw that) you could use document.activeElement or since you're using jQuery you could do $(':focus').

EDIT: take your openWindow variable and set it as `openWindow = $(':focus');` and as for the 3rd item you added you would have to save the active sticky in the localstorage of the page and just update it each time you change which sticky is active. Here's some info on localstorage [localstorage MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the resize event with the resize of jQuery

```
$("textarea").resizable({
    resize: function() {
       //resize your div
    }
});
```

For the sticky notes: how do you define the variable openedWindow?